# truffle migration fails, but initial migration was mined

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, quorum

I am trying to deploy [this contract](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/simplestorage.sol) on a private permissioned Quorum network. The migration fails on the `1_initial_migration` process. If I try to repeat the process with:

```
sudo truffle migrate --network development --reset
```

I don't get any output on the console at all. When I try to deploy another contract with other network configurations I also get no output to the console.
Without a console output it is hard to find out what is wrong.

**Is this normal behaviour of truffle?**

Here is the first migration process, which failed. The `eth.blockNumber` was increased after this, even if it failed.

What does the error stand for: `Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits`
?

```
Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      1337
> Block gas limit: 3758096384


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xd56cfd9d7bfa56b2s30138bb9a348069e40e92c2b41da87a081f2070560075
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x17D3233DD54d2491b68c62b534Da313c29456A39
   > account:             0xC58A28d310c76e8298FA456381E6F2da9F046V54
   > balance:             1000000000
   > gas used:            245462
   > gas price:           0 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0 ETH


   ⠋ Saving migration to chain.Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
```

**EDIT:**
My truffle-config.js looks as follows:

```
   development: {
        //provider: () => new HDWalletProvider("privateKey", "http://127.0.0.1"),
        host: "127.0.0.1",  
        port: 22000,          
        network_id: "*",      
        from: "0xC58A28d310c76e8298FA456381E6F2da9F046V54",
        gasPrice: 0,
        gas: 4500000
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention what Quorum config was for this, but we have seen this issue before with Truffle and Quorum running in Raft consensus mode. Please see this https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/issues/148

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What exactly would you like to know? I am running `raft`, I am starting it with `--permissioned` or do you mean with config the `config` field within the genesis.json

Comment: I mean contents of your genesis.json, but cli options also are useful for determining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an exceedingly high block gas limit. Try reducing it to below 2147483647.

PS You might also like to look at Etherlime, which provides a nice alternative to truffle migrations that's simpler and has fewer ways to go wrong.

Comment: Not the gas limit of your transaction, the network's block gas limit.

Comment: I haven't used quorum but I guess your mining/validating nodes have a genesis.json or similar? It should be in there.

Comment: I have set the chain gas limit via the flag `--targetgaslimit 2000000000` but still doesn't help

Comment: Hi, Quorum basically ignores gas limit configuration since it doesnt operate quiet like geth does. Most likely this is unrelated to the issue. Thanks,